# How to set div to go outside of bootstrap card borders?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, devexpress

I'm using bootstrap v4 and devexpress. That dropdown div is created by devexpress.
[image: Example]

Comment: share your code plz

Comment: It seems the dropdown menu div is inside the parent box div. In that case, if the menu is only HTML & CSS I would try an `overflow-y:visible` or `overflow-y:auto` on the parent div.

Comment: @GeorgeChond Yeap overflow:visible solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added `overflow:visible` to the parent div.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30797764)

Comment: @Shunya This one is an answer. See comments to the question.